Disabling Azure Extension during SQL Server 2022 installation via command-line
I am performing an installation of SQL Server 2022 (v16.x) Express using a command line setup. I would like to skip the installation of the Azure Extension for SQL Server, which is enabled by default.

I tried using this command line:
SQLEXPRADV_x64_ITA.exe /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES=SQLEngine 
     /ERRORREPORTING=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL 
     /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" 
     /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXP2022" /x:C:\MSSQLExpress2022\

I specified the /FEATURES=SQLEngine argument, hoping that since the Azure Extension is installed separately via /FEATURES=AZUREEXTENSION, specifying only SQLEngine would implicitly disable the extension. However, this does not work, and the Azure Extension is still installed and enabled.
Is there a command line argument, configuration file setting, or other approach that can be used during the SQL Server 2022 Express setup to either:

Skip the Azure Extension installation step entirely, or
Leave the "Azure Extension for SQL Server" checkbox unchecked (equivalent to manually deselecting it during the GUI setup)?

I have searched the documentation and online resources but have not found a definitive answer. Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

setup.exe /qs /ACTION=Uninstall /FEATURES=AZUREEXTENSION  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS seems to do the trick according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver16#install-and-connect-to-azure

sorry, it doesn't work. It uninstalls a feature already installed. I need to disable installation of specific feature.

No it doesn't, This command will not physically uninstall the Azure extension for SQL Server. Instead, the command will mark this feature as not selected in the setup. To remove the Azure resource for this instance, go to Azure portal and delete. it doesn't seem like you read the documentation you're reading

The documentation is quite ambiguous, I've just tried a few minutes ago: SQLEXPRADV_x64_ITA.exe /ACTION=Uninstall /FEATURES=AZUREEXTENSION /x:C:\MSSQLExpress2022\ And the error is "There are validation errors on this page. Click OK to close this dialog box. Review errors at the bottom of the setup page, then provide valid parameters." [Error Message] There are no valid SQL Server 2022 features to perform this operation. [Details] Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException: There are no valid SQL Server 2022 features to perform this operation.

If I use the following command line: SQLEXPRADV_x64_ITA.exe /ACTION=Uninstall /FEATURES=AZUREEXTENSION /x:C:\MSSQLExpress2022\ How can I specify to install SQLEngine?

Does it work if you combine /Action=Install  /Action=Uninstall /Features=Azure... into one call? I don't have the setup file available here but can try some at home
